# "До ответа оператора осталось 4 минуты"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Услышал такую *формулировку*, когда звонил в сервисный центр Xiaomi (кстати сказать, мне никто так и не ответил после трёх десятиминутных попыток: предлагали оставить голосовое сообщение в конце и сбрасывали). Мне она сразу показалась безграмотной и странной. Другое дело сказать "оператор ответит Вам через 4 минуты".

Хотелось бы узнать мнения остальных: действительно ли так не очень хорошо говорить и, если да, то почему. Объяснить вразумительно сам не могу, только "аргументы" типа "Ну разве так говорят?!". Вот разве только ещё такое соображение, что *до чего-то осталось сколько-то* говорят, имея в виду событие, мероприятие, но не ответ. Но это я так понимаю, не уверен в этом полностью.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу проблем в такой формулировке. Да, ваш вариант, как бы это сказать, изящнее, что ли, но и исходный ничем не запрещен.

Даже не очень понимаю причины вашего неприятия. Могу только предположить, что вы замкнулись на основном значения слова "ответ" - нечто, содержащее информацию по заданному вопросу или проблеме.

Но ведь "ответ" - это еще и действие, процесс, сама процедура отвечания. И в этом значении ответ ничем не хуже, скажем, старта ракеты, до которого "в запасе четырнадцать минут". Именно это имелось в виду у ваших киберсобеседников. Так что тут можно говорить разве что о контекстной неприемлемости, но никак не о грамматической.

А вариант "до **начала** ответа [оператора] осталось N минут" вас не смущает? Но ведь это то же самое, только более строго.

Comment: "До начала" ещё хуже)) Нет, я не замкнулся: конечно, я понимаю, что под ответом понимается действие.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  *"До начала" ещё хуже* - во как... Тогда мне трудно комментировать: не могу понять причин. А какие-нибудь еще процессы, помимо "ответа", вызывают подобное неприятие? *"До вопроса осталось пять мин"? "До зеленого сигнала осталась   60 сек"? "До визита налоговой осталось двое суток"?!* Хоть бы поймать эту ситуацию в вашем понимании.

Comment: Все эти варианты я бы переформулировал: "Зелёный зажжётся через минуту", "Инспектор налоговой придёт через двое суток" (или проще "дня дня"). Но "До старта Зеленоградского полумарафона (например) осталось столько-то" звучит, по-моему, вполне приемлемо, и то только отдельно (например, на сайте данного старта или серии пробегов), а не внутри какого-то повествования или любого цельного текста.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой "До Нового года - 15 минут [,все - к столу]!"? Если уж и это не нравится, то не знаю, что и сказать... Впрочем, в любом случае - не знаю. )))

Comment: *До Нового года - 15 минут, все к столу!* Тут всё прекрасно, вообще лучше и не придумаешь. Ведь НГ тут праздник. "До начала весны (календарной) осталось полчаса" — нормально звучит, единственное, что не совсем естественно ждать именно строгого времени начала суток (полуночи). Но и это нормально: если от того, что чувствуешь радость чисто от изменения статуса (зимы на весну), пускай тебе будет от этого хорошо на душе.)) Хотя можно порадовать ей и утром. Но не об этом речь. А высказывания типа "до какого-то действия (чьего-то) осталось сколько-то времени" звучат очень странно.

Comment: Возникла идея! Может быть, оттого они звучат странно, что именно в такой формулировке кажется, что всё чётко запрограммировано.

Comment: Поясню последнюю мысль про запрограммированность. "До зелёного сигнала осталось..." — тут мы точно знаем, когда он зажжётся, поэтому такая фраза вполне сойдёт. Про налоговую, если мы точно знаем, когда она явится, тоже ещё можно так сказать. А ответит оператор совсем не факт, что через три минуты, это только примерно, а нам пытаются преподнести это так, что всё запрограммировано и точно известно когда он ответит. В формулировке "оператор ответит через 4 минуты" легче простить ошибку, а "до ответа осталось" невольно воспринимаешь гораздо буквальнее, прагматичнее.

Answer (score 1):

Такая формулировка мне тоже не нравится. Почему - не могу объяснить. Скорее всего, просто потому, что так не принято говорить (в подобной ситуации). Формально не к чему придраться.

Comment: Я рад! В нашем полку прибыло!))

Answer (score 0):

Падежная форма ***до ответа*** со значением времени встречается в текстах, например:  При этом **период времени до ответа** пользователя не определен ― пользователь может дать ответ в течение нескольких секунд или через несколько минут.  «Информационные технологии», 2004.03.29]

Конечно, форма имеет терминологический характер, можно было бы рассчитывать на бОльшую вежливость по отношению к клиенту, например: **Пожалуйста, подождите, вам ответят через 4 минуты.**

Comment: Не знаю, мне кажется, что невежливость заключается не в отсутствии слова "пожалуйста" и не в более краткой формулировке, это для меня уже большая мелочь по сравнению с тем, что мне действительно здесь не нравится.

Comment: А какой  вариант вас устроил бы?

Comment: Тот, что я предложил в конце первого абзаца, вполне бы устроил. Ваш тоже устроил бы, но в меньшей степени. Безличное не так приятно слышать, но всё равно в тысячу раз лучше того, который у них.

Comment: В моем варианте не безличное, а неопределенно-личное предложение, это как раз тот случай, когда  производитель действия неважен. А у Вас присутствует лишняя информация - зачем называть отвечающее лицо именно оператором?

Comment: А-а, простите, не знал, как точно называется. Вроде операторами называют работников всяких служб поддержки, которые отвечают на звонки. А чем это плохо?

Comment: Это нормально, просто лишняя информация.